# Missing Features in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, login-screen, desktop-background, privacy

I have recently upgraded to  Ubuntu 12.04, and 2 new features that I have seen advertised on various websites are not on my version:

- Individual wallpapers on login screen
- Privacy options in 'settings'

Is there a way of getting these features, or have they just been removed?

P.S. I upgraded to 12.04 from 11.10 via the upgrade tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, I never was a fan of upgrades. Sometimes they simply break your system, sometimes leave out features, and sometimes are just plain dumb. Next time try a clean install. Generally installing clean leaves you with a better boot time, better response, and guaranteed speed.

Comment: Yeah, I think your right. I'll try it tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

**1. Privacy Options**

To access the privacy options click on "Session Indicator" and select "System Settings".

[image]

In "System Settings" click on "Privacy".

[image]

If privacy options are not available, please try this:

To open the terminal press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install activity-log-manager-control-cente
```

Then restart your system.

**2. Personalised Login Screen**

You'll get personalised login screen automatically when you'll change your desktop wallpaper (use something other than the default wallpaper). Your desktop wallpaper will automatically be used as your login screen background.

Comment: Hasn't happened for me since I upgraded to 12.04. Not to big of and issue for me but would like it to happen. I have had numerous backgrounds and only have had the default background at logins.

Comment: May be this will helps you: [What are the criteria for a user background to become login background on user selection?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/123721/what-are-the-criteria-for-a-user-background-to-become-login-background-on-user-s)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the privacy option doesn't even appear in system settings. Also, the wallpaper doesn't change automatically with the user.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with backgrounds not showing up on the login screen.  However, the problem only occurred when I tried to use files I transferred from a back-up external harddrive.  It turns out it is simply a permissions issue.  If you copied files from another location, they may only be user/group readable (but not other/world readable).  Since the global login screen doesn't have your personal permissions, it cannot access the background images unless they are world readable (don't make them world writable though).

So find the background(s) you want to use, and then change their permissions as so:

chmod o-r [some file with bad permissions]

This will hopefully resolve your login screen issue.